# What are the multiple drivers in this code?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

Code:

```
module controller_module(st_rst, clk, mem_rst,dis_rst, pe_rst, two_rst, three_rst, count, state ,two_end, s_end_1, s_end_2 , s_end_3, s_end_4, s3_end_22, s3_end_21, s3_end_12 ,s3_end_11, en_dis, 
                          input_11, input_12, input_13, input_14,
                          input_21, input_22, input_23, input_24,
                          input_31, input_32, input_33, input_34,
                          input_41, input_42, input_43, input_44,
                           filter_11,   filter_12,   filter_13 ,
                            filter_21,    filter_22,   filter_23 ,    
                             filter_31,    filter_32,   filter_33);


    input clk, st_rst;
    output two_end;
    output wire mem_rst, pe_rst, two_rst, three_rst, dis_rst;
    reg pe_rst, two_rst, three_rst, mem_rst, dis_rst;
    
    output s_end_1, s_end_2, s_end_3, s_end_4;
    output s3_end_22, s3_end_21, s3_end_12, s3_end_11;
    output en_dis;
    output [7:0] input_11, input_12, input_13, input_14,
                  input_21, input_22, input_23, input_24,
                  input_31, input_32, input_33, input_34,
                  input_41, input_42, input_43, input_44,
                  filter_11,   filter_12,   filter_13 ,
                  filter_21,    filter_22,   filter_23 ,    
                  filter_31,    filter_32,   filter_33;
 

    
    reg two_end;
    reg s_end_1;
    reg s_end_2;
    reg s_end_3 ;
    reg s_end_4 ;
    reg s3_end_22 ;
    reg s3_end_21 ;
    reg s3_end_12 ;
    reg s3_end_11;
    reg [7:0] input_11, input_12, input_13, input_14,
        input_21, input_22, input_23, input_24,
        input_31, input_32, input_33, input_34,
        input_41, input_42, input_43, input_44,
        filter_11,   filter_12,   filter_13 ,
        filter_21,    filter_22,   filter_23 ,    
        filter_31,    filter_32,   filter_33;
    
    reg en_dis;

    output[2:0] state;
    reg [2:0] state;    

    output [5:0] count; 
    reg [5: 0] count;
    
    reg [2:0] next_state;   
      
    //counter
    always @ (posedge clk )
    
    begin
      if(st_rst == 1'b1) 
        count <= 0;  **//here**
      else
      count <= count + 1;
    end

    //state change
    always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      if(st_rst == 1'b1)
        state <= 3'b101;
      else
        state <= next_state;
    end

    //mode change
    always @ (state, count)
    begin
        case(state) 
        3'b101://reset & initialize
        begin
            mem_rst =1'b1;
            dis_rst =1'b1;      
                pe_rst = 1'b1;
                three_rst = 1'b1;
                two_rst = 1'b1; 
                next_state = 0;
                two_end = 1'b0;
          s_end_1 = 1'b0;
          s_end_2= 1'b0;
          s_end_3 = 1'b0;
          s_end_4 = 1'b0;
    
          s3_end_22 = 1'b0;
          s3_end_21 = 1'b0;
          s3_end_12 = 1'b0;
          s3_end_11 = 1'b0;
          en_dis = 1'b0;
          input_11=1; 
          input_12=2; 
          input_13=3; 
          input_14=4;
          input_21=5; 
          input_22=6; 
          input_23=7; 
          input_24=8;
          input_31=9; 
          input_32=10; 
          input_33=11; 
          input_34=12;
          input_41=13; 
          input_42=14; 
          input_43=15; 
          input_44=16;
          filter_11=1;   
          filter_12=2;   
          filter_13=3;
          filter_21=4;    
          filter_22=5;   
          filter_23=6;    
          filter_31=7;    
          filter_32=8;   
          filter_33=9;
 
                
        end
                
        3'b000://start when st_rst changes to 0
        begin
              mem_rst = 1'b0;       
              dis_rst = 1'b0;   
                pe_rst = 1'b0;
                three_rst = 1'b0;
                two_rst = 1'b0; 
                count = 0; ***//here***
                next_state = 1;
                
        end
        3'b001://pe mode
        begin
          if(count == 6'd10)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b1;
            end
            
            else if(count == 6'd11)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b0;
                s_end_1 = 1'b1; 
            end
            
          else if(count == 6'd20)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b1;
            end
            
            else if(count == 6'd21)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b0;
                s_end_2 = 1'b1;
            end
            
          else if(count == 6'd30)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b1;
            end
            
            else if(count == 6'd31)
            begin
                pe_rst = 1'b0;
                s_end_3 = 1'b1;
            end
            
            else if(count == 6'd41)
            begin
              pe_rst = 1'b1;
              s_end_4 = 1'b1;
                next_state = 2;
                count = 0;
            end
        end

        3'b010://3by3 mode
        begin
          if(count == 9)
            begin
              s3_end_22 = 1'b1;
            end
          else if(count == 10)
            begin
              s3_end_21 = 1'b1;
            end
          else if(count == 13)
            begin
            s3_end_12 = 1'b1;
            end
          else if(count == 14)
            begin
              s3_end_11 = 1'b1;
            end   
            else if(count == 16)
              begin
                next_state = 3;
                count = 0;
              end
        end
        
        3'b011://2by2 mode
        begin
          if(count == 16)
            two_end = 1'b1;         
            else if(count == 18)              
              begin
                  next_state = 4;
                  count = 0;
              end   
        end
        
        
        3'b100://display mode
        begin
         en_dis = 1'b1; 
         next_state = 4;
         count = 0;
            
        end
        
        
        endcase
    end
```

Error:

```
[DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net cont/Q[0] has multiple drivers: cont/count_reg[0]__0/Q, and cont/count_reg[0]/Q.(5 more like this)
```

Why does the variable "`count`" have the multiple driver net? I checked the netlist, and under `count` which locates the `//counter` line, and `//starts when st_rst changes to 0` occurred the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You make assignments to `count` from 2 different `always` blocks.  You must only make assignments to a signal from one `always` block, otherwise you have contention ("multiple drivers").

The sequential `always` block looks fine: `@ (posedge clk )`

You should remove the *assignments* to `count` from the combinational `always` block: `always @ (state, count)`

If you need to set `count` to 0 under other conditions, you could add them to the sequential block.